# Using Angular Dragula without RequireJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs, dragula

I would love to implement Drag and Drop in my Angular project using the angular-dragula module (https://github.com/bevacqua/angular-dragula). However, it seems to be heavily dependent on RequireJS. I've not used Require for a while and only then for an example app or two. Is there an easy way to untangle Require from this module?

The author seems to think it is simple (https://github.com/bevacqua/angular-dragula/issues/23) and has shut down similar questions as well without a real explanation. I've looked at the code and don't see how to load the module without adding RequireJS to my project (which I don't want to do). Am I stuck with either not using this module or adding Require or is there a way to use this without Require?

Comment: Skimming through the source it looks like the `dist/angular-dragula.js` depends on require but the minified version might not. Have you tried using the minified version to see if it works?

Comment: Yeah, I did and it didn't seem to work. Part of the problem is that it also expects to be initialized by passing in angular so I'm having a hard time just including it as a dependency in angular.

Comment: I think you can pass it an instance of the global variable `angular` , since `require('angular')` would return that anyway.

Comment: Try [AMD clean](https://www.npmjs.com/package/amdclean). Let us know if that works.

Comment: I posted my answer below. We can bypass require if everything is loaded in the right order and you use the variable names the author created. As for AMD clean, I did not get to the point of trying that. Thanks for the help everyone.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

OK, after help from those who commented (thanks everyone!), I was able to get this to work. There are a couple things that you need to do. First, I was bundling this module with the rest of my modules and trying to call it. That will not work because it needs to initialize with a parameter (`angular`). Therefore, you need to do the following:

1. Add a reference to angular-dragula.js (or the min version) to your index.html page below the declaration for angular but above where you create your app.
2. When you declare the dependencies for your app, specify `angularDragula(angular)` (not in quotes).
3. Use dragula as you normally would. If you need to access the service, the name would be `angularDragula`.

For example, here is my declaration of app:

```
var app = angular.module('app', [
  'ngRoute',
  angularDragula(angular)
]);
```

And then to get a simple list to be drag and drop capable, this is my html:

```
<div dragula='"bag-one"' dragula-model="vm.items">
    <div ng-repeat="item in vm.items">{{ item }}</div>
</div>
```

Note that I do not declare angularDragula anywhere, unlike the examples. In the example the author gives, he requires `angular` and creates the `angular` variable and then he requires `angular-dragula` and creates the `angularDragula` variable. This is not needed if you are not using `RequireJS` as long as you load the scripts in the right order.

Comment: I'm trying this in my ionic app. I don't explicitly load angular in my index.html, ionic handles it. Does that change how I would do this? Doing as you describe `angularDragula` returns `function register(angular) {...` but calling it errors `cannot read property 'module' of undefined` at `var app = angular.module('dragula', ['ng']);`

Comment: I'm loading `dist/angular-dragula.js` after ionic but before my `app.js` and declaring `angularDragula(angular)` in my `app.js` dependencies(I've tried both before and after the ionic dependency is loaded with no difference).

Comment: nevermind It was working. I wasn't passing the correct dependency to my controller(dragulaService). Thanks for the great solution!

Comment: yes, it works! but now all my tests are failing: Error: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: angularDragula