# Use angular dragula without requirejs ends in failing js tests

Tags: angularjs, angular-dragula

I have the same issue as described here: [Using Angular Dragula without RequireJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33744487/using-angular-dragula-without-requirejs/33759865)

It works if do this:

```
var app = angular.module('app', [
  angularDragula(angular)
]);
<script src="node_modules/angularjs-dragula/dist/angularjs-dragula.js"></script>
```

But all the jasmine tests fail with: `Error: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: angularDragula`

Comment: Can you post your configuration for the test? You should have an array of file paths which includes angularjs-dragula.js, and the files must be ordered correctly (dependencies must come before the files that depend on them).

Comment: yeah, that was the problem. I use chutzpah, so in chutzpah.json I added the path to angular-dragula. Thanks. I guess you should create and answer with this so I can accept it and get the bounty ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your configuration file. You should have an array of file paths which includes angularjs-dragula.js, and the files must be ordered correctly (dependencies must come before the files that depend on them).